# Matlab - get date x-coordinate of button click on line plot using 'buttondownfcn'

Tags: matlab

Trying to get my head around Matlab's handling figure interactions.

I have a simple line graph to which I want to attach a click function using `ButtonDownFcn`. When the line is clicked I want the x-value of the click location to be displayed. However, the x-values are in `datetime` format. What I have so far is this

```
x = 0:pi/100:2*pi;
y = sin(x);
x = datetime(datevec(x+10));
f=plot(x,y);
f.ButtonDownFcn = @clickf;

function clickf(hObj,event)
    pt = event.IntersectionPoint;      
    if pt(3)==0
        x = num2ruler(pt(1),hObj.XAxis);
        disp(datestr(x));
    end
end
```

What I am missing is the way to access the figure's axes in the click function, as only clicks on the line element are handled. This is necessray so I can translate the relative x-value back to `datetime` using the `num2ruler` function.

Any hints are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't have the `num2ruler` function in my Matlab version so I can't run your example. The `hObj` returned in the callback is the handle of the `line` object. So if you want the handle of the `axes` you can query the "parent" property of `hObj`. So your line would become: `x = num2ruler(pt(1),hObj.Parent.XAxis);`

Comment: Awesome! I knew there was an easy solution to my problem. If you add that as an answer I will accept it!